# How to push to git subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I added a subtree on git which seems to be working. I went into the directory and made some changes and then pushed.

I noticed these changes show up in the parent project but the repository which I used as the source hasn't been updated.

I tried `git subtree push` which returns:

> You must provide the --prefix option.

Also `git subtree push --prefix=my/folder git@mygitrepo.com` which returns:

> You must provide `<repository> <ref>`

What is the correct way to push changes to the origin repo for my git subtree?

**Edit:** it was suggested that I do:

```
git subtree push --prefix=my/folder origin master
```

When I run the above it starts the process but ends up saying the branch is behind. So I run:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=my/folder origin master
```

Which returns "Already up to date"

Comment: You never mention doing a `commit` (which normally comes between making changes and pushing). Did you commit those changes to the subtree?

Comment: @crashmstr I commited the changes to the parent project, do I have to commit with the subtree command too?

Comment: Have you tried like this: `git subtree push origin master`? (Or whatever youre remote and the branch are called)

Comment: @Dan I hadn't but I'm trying now and I get "you must provide the --prefix option"

Comment: Oops, I was thinking submodule (which I have worked with) instead of subtree (which I have not worked with).

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Well, then do provide that too: `git subtree push --prefix=my/folder origin master`

Comment: @Dan thanks this got me a bit further. I posted results in my question as an edit.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Why are you doing a `pull` this time instead of a `push`? Btw there's no issue in the latter reply from `git`: it just tells you, your local is up to date with the remote.

Comment: @Dan I ran push and it said my repository was behind, so I ran pull which said it was up to date.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I see. Sorry, I missed that point. What exactly did it say? I assume it was behind, so it pushed, and now it's up to date. I don't really know all the details of you repo, but have a look at whether they are in sync. Try to use `git log`.

Comment: @Dan I wish there was a 'git subtree log' command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134786/discussion-between-dan-and-philip-kirkbride).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So, with some joint effort with @PhilipKirkbride, here's what we managed to figure out:

You need to put all the details in the command:

```
git subtree push --prefix=my/folder subtree_origin master
```

Where `master` is the branch in the subtree, and `subtree_origin` is just another remote, which happens to point to your subtree's git repository. You can also type the full repo URL.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5822464/dan)'s 2017 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42027940/6309) can be applied to any commit, not just HEAD.

See [commit 9a3e3ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a3e3ca2ba869f9fef9f8be390ed45457565ccd1), [commit 49470cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49470cd445166fbe778218c7618ea8ee78ca7d00), [commit 94389e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94389e7c81d47102f061b36a93e050d639fe3d40), [commit cb65514](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb6551447b8e0c35408b766ad605ba357f720a0d), [commit 6468784](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6468784dd2ca3ea2408f9915ab9b7ce136f0b024), [commit e9525a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9525a8a0291eb5ef0a81473d2b8c4d4b3b198c8), [commit 534ff90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/534ff90dbd74a81beee357220cfa026efc18fea6), [commit 5cdae0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cdae0f6fd76bd1c12304240a17a5a12632fbb12), [commit cbb5de8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbb5de8b83f3abde8f9b37b0048bc00344b6709b), [commit e4f8baa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4f8baa88a0b294e1e2d91728e728e14574d1d87), [commit bbffb02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbffb023830f9b68e2c461e47756579a5cd6ab7a), [commit 22d5507](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22d550749361ff2a480bc4263ae21919368851ed), [commit a94f911](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a94f911072eb096184d3b4daeb58722dc339d0d9), [commit e2b11e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2b11e42110f3c7082b4a5547eb535b0be6153e5), [commit 6d43585](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d43585a6865493b68e64f0b100ae801ed15d806), [commit f664304](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66430483645eb764135e5c79b753f1c09170ac8), [commit 8dc3240](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dc3240f5fc78aec1b1e6b10b94fa361bf016157), [commit d2f0f81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2f0f819547de35ffc923fc963f806f1656eb2ca), [commit 5a35697](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a3569774f7b6dcdbdf470ae1e40367200d987ec), [commit b04538d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b04538d99f07a2ac39a5314ec76bc9f07e5fd686), [commit b269976](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2699769792cfd56f77dfd6819d6654628176634), [commit db6952b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db6952b2b28627d43da5e0fdaefcea6c040ab581), [commit f1cd2d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1cd2d93c207a0db5d85bcaf5a7b71ea60ceecb5), [commit 63ac4f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63ac4f1ade9bccf4f0b863ffc95000ae1faff2a7), [commit c4566ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4566ab429c5a46a91c5b3bd351c545b91a2e593), [commit 40b1e1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40b1e1ec581e5f1e6fc3c0b317c0baf3c7817c43), [commit f700406](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7004069574a3d3a3fb1526c3b91448e8cb8995b), [commit f2bb7fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2bb7fef7a8d9a88cb440ad362863e510f5f2369), [commit 914d512](https://github.com/git/git/commit/914d5125510f50cd8761768f16970a29cbce909c), [commit 4c996de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c996deb4af99ce73c67d47ac9cfc9400c216ebf) (27 Apr 2021) by [Luke Shumaker (`LukeShu`)](https://github.com/LukeShu).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 44ccb76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44ccb7629a448fd4408f4ff7206df628a31dabed), 10 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49470cd445166fbe778218c7618ea8ee78ca7d00): push: allow specifying a local rev other than HEAD
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Luke Shumaker</sup>

> `git subtree split` lets you specify a rev other than HEAD.
> '[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49470cd445166fbe778218c7618ea8ee78ca7d00/Documentation/git-push.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> lets you specify a mapping between a local thing and a remot ref.
>
> So smash those together, and have git subtree push let you specify which local thing to run split on and push the result of that split to the remote ref.

[`git subtree` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49470cd445166fbe778218c7618ea8ee78ca7d00/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L118-L124) now includes:

> ### `push <repository> [+][<local-commit>:]<remote-ref>`
>
> Does a 'split' using the  subtree of `<local-commit>` and then does a 'git push' to push the result to the `<repository>` and `<remote-ref>`.
>
> This can be used to push your subtree to different branches of the remote repository.
> Just as with 'split', if no `<local-commit>` is given, then HEAD is used.
> The optional leading '`+`' is ignored.

That means this will work:

```
git subtree push --prefix="sub dir" --annotate="*" ./"sub proj" HEAD^:from-mainline
                                                                ^^^^^^
```

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), `git subtree` actually works on Windows.

See [commit 77f37de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77f37de39fa96e4e5d59cda1e7e85c4784b48ee9), [commit f7ee88f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7ee88f1d09ce47b8e12b52a2f19c7867ae10b29) (14 Jun 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e22ac8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e22ac8b1269d1dca4ffce0bf2cde825763623d0a), 08 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7ee88f1d09ce47b8e12b52a2f19c7867ae10b29): fix the `GIT_EXEC_PATH` sanity check to work on Windows
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [22d5507](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22d550749361ff2a480bc4263ae21919368851ed) ("`subtree`: don't fuss with PATH", 2021-04-27, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44ccb7629a448fd4408f4ff7206df628a31dabed) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49f38e2de47a401fc2b0f4cce38e9f07fb63df48)), git subtree was broken thoroughly on Windows.
>
> The reason is that it assumes Unix semantics, where `PATH` is colon-separated, and it assumes that `$GIT_EXEC_PATH:` is a verbatim prefix of `$PATH`.
> Neither are true, the latter in particular because `GIT_EXEC_PATH` is a Windows-style path, while `PATH` is a Unix-style path list.
>
> Let's make extra certain that `$GIT_EXEC_PATH` and the first component of `$PATH` refer to different entities before errorring out.
>
> We do that by using the `test <path1> -ef <path2>` command that verifies that the inode of `<path1>` and of `<path2>` is the same.
>
> Sadly, this construct is non-portable, according to [`test` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).
> However, it does not matter in practice because we still first look whether `$GIT_EXEC_PREFIX` is string-identical to the first component of `$PATH`.
> This will give us the expected result everywhere but in Git for Windows, and Git for Windows' own Bash *does* handle the `-ef` operator.
>
> Just in case that we *do* need to show the error message *and* are running in a shell that lacks support for `-ef`, we simply suppress the error output for that part.
>
> This fixes [`git-for-windows/git` issue 3260](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3260)

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), `git subtree` (in `contrib/`) is faster.

See [commit 3ce8888](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce8888fb499f9646b770306be6e2c7674a75199) (08 Dec 2021) by [James Limbouris (`jamesl-dm`)](https://github.com/jamesl-dm).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9b6eda0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b6eda0785e9e6422e0a975901514043a05a9e47), 10 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce8888fb499f9646b770306be6e2c7674a75199): fix argument handling in `check_parents`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: James Limbouris</sup>

> [315a84f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/315a84f9aa0e2e629b0680068646b0032518ebed) ("`subtree`: use commits before rejoins for splits", 2018-09-28, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7b07376e5fe416e9aab571e4711e630f9387886) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c670b1f876521c9f7cd40184bf7ed05aad843433)) changed the signature of `check_parents` from '`check_parents` [REV...]' to '`check_parents` `PARENTS_EXPR` INDENT'.
> In other words the variable list of parent revisions became a list embedded in a string.
> However it neglected to unpack the list again before sending it to `cache_miss,` leading to incorrect calls whenever more than one parent was present.
> This is the case whenever a merge commit is processed, with the end result being a loss of performance from unecessary rechecks.
>
> The indent parameter was subsequently removed in [e9525a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9525a8a0291eb5ef0a81473d2b8c4d4b3b198c8) ("`subtree`: have $indent actually affect indentation", 2021-04-27, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44ccb7629a448fd4408f4ff7206df628a31dabed) listed in [batch #15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49f38e2de47a401fc2b0f4cce38e9f07fb63df48)), but the argument handling bug remained.
>
> For consistency, take multiple arguments in `check_parents`, and pass all of them to `cache_miss` separately.

Answer (score -1):

normally the output dir, such as `dist` or `public` are ignored in the .gitignore. If you want to use `git subtree` on these paths, you have to

```
git add <DIR to be subtree pushed>
```

then `git commit`.

When finished above two steps, you are okay to `git subtree push` those generated dir into a separate branches of your repository.